# UITableView doesn't remember its scroll position after dismiss moviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with custom cells,in this table a list of video is showing 10 by 10 from server using pagination concept. when you click on video list then video start playing in moviePlayerController but when you click on done `Button` of moviePlayerController then your video list is refreshed .
I want to stop this refreshing and want to see `UITableView` same as before playing video.

Please see the code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    CurrentVideoIndex =indexPath;
    NSDictionary *VideoUrlDic = [videoList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *VideoUrl = [VideoUrlDic objectForKey:@"playUrl"];
    //NSLog(@"VideoUrl is ::%@",VideoUrl);

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:VideoUrl];

    moviePlayerController= [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [[moviePlayerController moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
    //[[moviePlayerController moviePlayer] setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
    [[moviePlayerController moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    //[[moviePlayerController moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
    //[[moviePlayerController moviePlayer] setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerController];
}
-(void)videoPlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification  {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer stop];
    moviePlayerController = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:moviePlayerController  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerController.moviePlayer];

    if (![[self modalViewController] isBeingDismissed])
    {
        [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
        [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self hideProgress];
    }

//     [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:CurrentVideoIndex atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop  animated:NO];
    //loading=NO;
}

#pragma UIScroll View Method::

    - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
        if (!loading) {
            float endScrolling = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
            if (endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
            {
                [self performSelector:@selector(loadDataDelayed) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];

            }
        }
    }

    #pragma UserDefined Method:::
    -(void)loadDataDelayed{

        counter +=10;
        NSString *count = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter];
        NSLog(@"count value after Scrolling  is :::%@",count);
        [self createConnection:count];
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a `viewWillAppear:` method?

Comment: in viewWillAppear nothing done by me

Comment: Have you just created a new account to repost this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872990/how-to-stop-reload-tableview-after-dissmiss-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller ? You should have just updated the original question.

Comment: do you use any "[self.tableView reloadData];"?

Comment: put break point on view did load and view will appear and in table view delegate methods to check for calling pattern

Comment: i check calling pattern after click on done button of mvplayercontroller then.firstly called viewwillappear then call videoPlayBackDidFinish .and viewdidload is not called after dismiss movieplayer

Comment: Quang Ha . i am using [self.tableView reloadData] only one time after parsing xml data and add new 10 video list in tableview array.

Comment: what exactly are you doing in hideProgress: method??

Comment: it's method to hide progress indicator

Comment: @user2621383 : To guide you I need to know your viewWillAppear() code!

Comment: NSString *count = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter];
    [self createConnection:count];  these lines of code are written in viewwillappear. count is for page no.means 10 by 10 data

Comment: As i explained your another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858481/after-dissmiss-movieplayercontroller-table-view-is-reload-automatically/17875713#17875713

Your `UITableView` datasource methods will be call again. 
You might be initializing videoList again in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

When the video player is opened the presentmodalviewcontroller is opened and when you press the done button it dismiss the modalviewcontroller due to which whatever you have initialize would be released and again the whole view is called, so to avoid that write the code in viewwillappear method.

Which would create the tableview when you press the done button once again, thats the only solution when you dismiss any controller. In viewwillappear method use

> NSLog(@"");

statement you would come to know what i am trying to say

Comment: you mean to say i have to init and alloc my table array in viewwillappear method.i try this but problem exit like before.